# Choosing CIs for Effects and Interactions from Within-Subject Repeated Measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, confidence-interval, data-visualization, repeated-measures

I have been reading the work of Loftus and Masson but am still confused. I will ask very specific questions, but ultimately I am interested in understanding the material such that I feel comfortable computing a CI for any given pattern of interest.

I have a 2x2x2 completely within-subject factorial design with factors A, B, and C. I run a repeated measures ANOVA in R using `m = aov(y ~ A*B*C + Error(S/(A*B*C)))` where S is the random effect of subject.

If I'm interested in the pattern underlying the main effect of A such that I want to plot a common CI around the overall mean of each level (A1B.C., A2B.C.), what error term do I use? Further, if I want to plot a common CI around the mean of each level (A1B1C1, A2B1C1, ___, A2B2C2) to look at the effect of A each other factor level combination, what error term do I use?

If I'm interested in the pattern underlying the interaction between A and B such that I want to plot a common CI around the overall mean difference of A at each level of B (A1B1C. - A2B1C., A1B2C. - A2B2C.), what error term do I use? Further, if I want to also see how C comes into play: (A1B1C1 - A2B1C1, A1B2C1 - A2B2C1, A1B1C2 - A2B1C2, A1B2C2 - A2B2C2)...

Similarly, for the interaction between A, B, and C: ( A1B1C1 - A2B1C1 - (A1B2C1 - A2B2C1) - (A1B1C2 - A2B1C2 - (A1B2C2 - A2B2C2)) )...

One thing I have noticed is that a model reduction approach for main effects (A1B.C. and A2B.C. for each subject) gives you the same error term as the error term of the full model divided by 4. Model reduction for two-way interactions (A1B1C. - A2B1C. and A1B2C. - A2B2C. for each subject) gives leads to exactly the error term of the full model. Finally, model reduction for three-way interactions ( A1B1C1 - A2B1C1 - (A1B2C1 - A2B2C1) and A1B1C2 - A2B1C2 - (A1B2C2 - A2B2C2) for each subject) leads to the error term of the full model multiplied by 4.

Comment: For your "thing I have noticed" what do you mea by full model? Do you mean a one-way ANOVA? There is no "the error term" of the full model of a 2x2x2 repeated measures ANOVA.

Comment: I mean that the error term for the main effect (first sentence) of the full model (2x2x2) is the same as that of the model reduction approach which involves averaging over factors B and C.